# Why is data.entrySet().iterator() ordered in a different order, compared to the HashMap<Long, String> data?

Tags: java, json, iterator, hashmap

I have input data (Timestamp, Json string) which I store in a `HashMap<Long, String>`. To process the JSON string I use an iterator.

I use `Iterator<Entry<Long, String>> it = data.entrySet().iterator();` to get the entrySet as iterator.

My problem is now that the HashMap is organized as follows:

```
 123,{String1} 
 124,{String2} 
 125,{String3}
```

Better expressed: I add A to the HashMap, Z to the HashMap, E to the HashMap, I to the HashMap. I expect the order A, Z, E, I and I want the same order in the iterator.

If I put it in an iterator I get:

```
124, {String2}
123, {String1}
125, {String3}
```

The order of the itarator is different from the HashMap order. For me the order of the iterator has to be exactly the same as the order of the HashMap. What I'm doing wrong, that the iterator is changing the order of the data?

Comment: (If it's insertion order you want, rather than natural sort order, then there's `LinkedHashMap`.)

Comment: Hash map's are not sorted... your hash map is not 'organized' as anything!  If you want the data set sorted then use a TreeMap

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself wrong. It's not about sorting, it is about the order. I put A to the HashMap, B to the HashMap, Z to the HashMap and D to the HashMap. With the debugger I see a order A, B, Z, D and I expect the same order in the iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) documentation says that

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

So you should not rely on the order while you are iterating views `entrySet` or `keySet` or `values`.

Some implementations of `Map` such as `TreeMap` provide ordering guarantee as @Oleg S and @Smutje have already suggested.

Comment: Copying from other answers?

Comment: @OlegS. You cannot assume that it was because I copied or something. All users at stackoverflow edit the answers multiple times to make the answer more complete and finished. You and me happen to have same answer does not mean I have copied.

Comment: I think it was rather concurrently writing. ;-)

Comment: @OlegS. Anyway I also added the reference to both answers in my post which just goes to show how `unwilling` I was on copying. You should't be so critical about same answers. You will find some questions where every one has same answer. All of them copied each other?? No that's not the way a community works. Everyone gets an equal chance to represent their answer. Being relatively new, you will find out soon.

Comment: You edited your answer well after the other two were posted adding information first about TreeMap and then about SortedMap, so it has nothing to do with coming up with an original idea at roughly the same time.

Comment: @OlegS. you are free to make assumptions. But I would suggest you not to judge someone so soon.

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` is not organised in any particular order, or more precisely, the order is not guaranteed. If you want an ordered map, use `SortedMap` with a `TreeMap` implementation providing a `Comparator` if you need to override the default ordering of keys.

Answer (score 2):

Additional to the above findings,

Even you can use **LinkedHashMap** as given below,**LinkedHashMap** will make sure values stored in the order of insertion.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
    Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(1, "oneone");
    map.put(3, "twoone");
    map.put(2, "threeone");
    map2.put(1, "oneone");
    map2.put(3, "twoone");
    map2.put(2, "threeone");
    for(Entry<Integer, String> entry:map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());

    }

    for(Entry<Integer, String> entry:map2.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());

    }

}
```

Here result will be,

**1

3

2

1

2

3**

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from the `java.util.Map` API doc: "The Map interface provides three collection views, which allow a map's contents to be viewed as a set of keys, collection of values, or set of key-value mappings. The order of a map is defined as the order in which the iterators on the map's collection views return their elements. Some map implementations, like the TreeMap class, make specific guarantees as to their order; others, like the HashMap class, do not."